# GitHub actions inputs don't get printed with echo

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I've been trying to set up the most basic GitHub action that can be triggered via API, and I managed to trigger it, but now I'm having trouble passing down the "inputs" and using them in the jobs...
I tried reading the documentation and all, and it should work but I'm probably missing some syntax or something...
Here's the action code:

```
name: Test

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    inputs:
      body:
        default: 'testdefaultvalue'
        description: 'Test desc'
        required: true
        
        
jobs:
  print_inputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Print inputs
      run: echo "The inputs are ${{ inputs.body }}"
```

And here's the body that I'm trying to send using POST which hits and triggers this action

```
{"event_type": "my_event", "client_payload": {"body": "Hello, world!"}}
```

I keep getting only the first part of the echo, like on this screenshot
[image]

I even tried just printing out the inputs body with the default value using a different kinds of syntaxes but nothing worked. Hopefully, this is not a duplicate and someone will help me and it'll be useful for someone in the future as well!

Comment: Try: `echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.body }}`

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch

Comment: @Azeem It's working!! Post it as an answer if you want.. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Awesome! :) You're welcome! Answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch), you need to refer to the complete event context to get the values.

So, this should work in your case:

```yaml
echo ${{ github.event.client_payload.body }}
```